# Is it always possible to write $\min\{ x_1, \dots, x_N \} = \min\Big\{ \min\{x_1, x_2\}, \min\{x_2, x_3\}, \dots, \min\{x_{N-1}, x_N\} \Big\}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does the following identity hold for any $N$?
$$
\min\{ x_1, \dots, x_N \} = \min\Big\{ \min\{x_1, x_2\}, \min\{x_2, x_3\}, \dots, \min\{x_{N-1}, x_N\} \Big\}
$$

Comment: Yes, you surely can.

Comment: Yes. If $\{ S_i\mid i\in I\}$ is any indexed collection of subsets of $S=\bigcup_i S_i$ then $\min S=\min\{\min S_i\mid i\in I\}$ (assuming the minima exist).

Comment: Yes; see [Sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly: suppose that there was some $\{x_i\}$ such that $\min\{x_i\} = m \neq \min\{\min\{x_k, x_{k+1}\}: 0 \leq k < i\}$.

Because $m$ is the minimum of $\{x_i\}$, we know that $m$ has to be some member of $\{x_i\}$, so let's say $m = x_a$.

Because $m$ is in $\{x_i\}$ we also know it is less than or equal to every value in $\{x_i\}$. We also know that every value in $\{\min\{x_k, x_{k+1}\}\}$ is in $\{x_i\}$ because they're all obtained by taking minimums of sets whose only members are members of $\{x_i\}$. So, $m$ must be less than or equal to every value in $\{\min\{x_k, x_{k+1}\}\}$, and the only way that $m$ is not the minimum of $\{\min\{x_k, x_{k+1}\}\}$ is that $m$ is not in $\{\min\{x_k, x_{k+1}\}\}$.

Let's say $a < N$, so $a + 1 \leq N$. If this is the case, then $\min\{x_a, x_{a+1}\} = x_a = m$ must be in the set. Otherwise, if $a = N$, then $\min\{x_{N-1}, x_N\} = x_N = m$ must be in the set. Either way, we've reached a contradiction, so our assumption that there was some $\{x_i\}$ such that the minimums of the two sets aren't equal must have been false.

Therefore, for every sequence $\{x_i\}, \min\{x_i\} = \min\{\min\{x_k, x_{k+1}\}: 0 \leq k < i\}$. This logic can be extended for any set of combinations where it's guaranteed that every element is listed at least once.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. It is even redundant (twice as many comparisons) and you could use

$$
\min\{ x_1, \dots, x_N \} = \min\Big\{ \min\{x_1, x_2\}, \min\{x_3, x_4\}, \dots, \min\{x_{N-1}, x_N\} \Big\}
$$

(or just $X_N$ in the end if $N$ is odd).

You can create more complex combinations, with more nesting, and still get the same result, provided every element appears at least once.